# I am getting a segmentation fault in this code and can't understand why?

Tags: c++

I am trying to code a program where it takes a program as an input and prints out all the comments written in that program in a separate line.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string str;

    while(getline(cin,str))    {
    int i;
       // cout<<str;

    for(i=0;str[i]!='/' && str[i+1] !='/';i++);
        //cout<<i;
    for(i;str[i]!='\n';i++) {
       // cout<<i;
        cout<<str[i];
    }
        cout<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault in this code and I can't understand why. This is part of a code of a problem in hackerrank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ide-identifying-comments/copy-from/12957153

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You should never trust user input to be what you expect. Who's to say the user won't enter an empty string here?

Comment: Martin, could you suggest a good debugger, I have always coded using ideone and have tried something like eclipse.

Comment: you will get index out of range exception, test whether i is less than size of str in your for loops.

Comment: @RohanArora gdb is a common debugger, but you have to run a local development environment, ideone doesn't fit for this. I'd recommend some decent IDE like Eclipse CDT for satisfying debug experience.

Comment: `for (i = 0; str[i] != '/' && str[i + 1] != '/'; i++)` no exit here  if there is no comment.

Comment: You could always use Visual Studio as it comes with a good debugger. Eclipse is good too. I think it is because you go out of bounds with the i++ and no proper checking of string end.

Comment: Also a potential kaboom if the last character on the line is /

Comment: You've been programming using ideone.com??? Man, this nonsense "cloud computing" movement is really dangerous! ideone is okay for sharing snippets but _not_ for actual development work....

Comment: `for (i; str[i] != '\n'; i++)` is doomed. `getline` discards the EOL.

Comment: Proper formatting will make your code readable in a way that currently it is ... not.

Comment: First of all getline returns std::string object not char *. You are treating std::string object as character array in rest of your code. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/. Secondly your loop never ends if input does not contain `//`.

Comment: @pitnal, [I recommend you read this.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) OP got that part right.

Answer (score 0):

As commented in your question your code is wrong. First you are treating std::string object, returned by getline, as character array. Secondly your for loops never end if there is no `//` or `\n` found in input string. So obviously it will crash. Below is the modified code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string str;

    while(getline(cin,str))    {
    int i;
       // cout<<str;

    size_t len = str.length();
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    for(i=0; (cstr[i]!='/' && cstr[i+1] !='/' && i < len); i++)
        //cout<<i;
    for(; cstr[i]!='\n' && i < len;i++) {
       // cout<<i;
        cout<<cstr[i];
    }
        cout<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want the tests for `i < len` to be __first__ so the short-circuit evaluation will work correctly and prevent reading past the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    while(getline(cin,str)) {
        int i, len = str.size();

        //always make sure that you are not accessing
        //contents after your string has ended
        for(i=0; i < (len - 1) && !(str[i] == '/' && str[i+1] == '/'); i++);

        //note that i here might be the last alphabet
        //if there's no comment
        if(i < len && str[i] != '/')
            i++;


        //checking if str[i] != '\n' is not a good idea
        //as c++ stl strings are not temrinated by '\n'
        if(i < len) {
            for(; i < len; i++)
                cout << str[i];
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also  note that both of the following codes won't terminate at the 4th character, c++ stl strings are not terminated by these characters.

```
string str = "hahahaha";
str[4] = '\n';
cout << str;

str[4] = '\0';
cout << str;
```

Comment: Now try and parse this line: `    cout << "\\I'm not a comment!" << endl;`

Comment: i am not trying to solve the problem, i am just trying to resolve the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to write and probably much faster than the other solutions to date.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        size_t loc = str.find("//");
        if (loc != str.npos)
        {
            std::cout << str.substr(loc + 2)<< std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is also wrong.

Here is a nice, clean, and simple state machine version. Also pretty close to worst-case for speed. Thing is it's closest to being right, even though it is also wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
enum states
{
    seeking1,
    seeking2,
    comment
};

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, str))
    {
        states state = seeking1;
        for (char ch:str)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case seeking1:
                    if (ch == '/')
                    {
                        state = seeking2;
                    }
                    break;
                case seeking2:
                    if (ch == '/')
                    {
                        state = comment;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state = seeking1;
                    }
                    break;
                case comment:
                    std::cout << ch;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (state == comment)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why are these approaches all wrong? Consider the line

```
cout << "Hi there! I am \\Not A Comment!" << endl;`
```

You can't just look at the `\\`, you also need the context. This is why the state machine above is the better option. It can be modified to handle, at the very least, states for handling strings and block comments.